# Force QCompleter to reappear if user selects directory

Tags: qt, qlineedit, qcompleter

I have a dialog where user selects file(s). I added `QCompleter` to the line edit, which automatically suggests next file name:

[image: image description]

However if user clicks on file, the suggestions disappear:

[image: image description]

I want them to reappear if directory is selected and display the files in that directory. I tried to do this inside the `QLineEdit::textChanged` signal. I connected it to such slot:

```
void ImportFromExcelDialog::pathChanged( const QString& path )
    if(path.length()>0) {
        QFileInfo info(path);
        if( info.exists() && info.isFile() && info.isReadable() ) {
            // File selected, do stuff with it
        }
        else {
            // If a directory
            if((info.exists() && info.isDir())) {
                if(!path.endsWith("/"))
                    ui->fileLineEdit->setText(path + "/");
                // Assume QCompleter* completer_; which is set in constructor
                if(completer_!=nullptr)
                    completer_->complete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that calling `complete()` shows the old list of files, the one for parent directory:

[image: image description]

I can click *telemetrie* as many times as I want and the display won't change.

So how to force `QCompleter` to reappear and handle the **new** value of the text field?

Comment: Try to create a `QTimer`, connect it to `complete()` slot and start it with a small delay.

Comment: Or better with a zero delay. It just puts an execution of the slot at the end of the event queue and it doesn't look like a hack that much.

Comment: @Tomas Well and is it possible to just call slot asynchronously like this? Something like Java's `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` or JavaScript's Node.js `process.nextTick`? Because using timer is still a hack to do just this...

Comment: Using the `QTimer` with the zero delay is in my opinion a valid way how to execute some code after all queued events are processed. But if you don't like it, you can also use the `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(completer_, "complete", Qt::QueuedConnection);`. Or emit a signal connected to the `complete()` slot with the `Qt::QueuedConnection`. But anyway, does it solve your problem?